# How to access shapefile m-values with pyqgis?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, linear-referencing

How can I access (read/write) m values of a line Shapefile using pyqgis?

I know how to do it with arcpy cursors (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Reading_geometries/002z0000001t000000/ ) but I don't know how to do it with pyqgis.

Is it possible with the QGIS python library?

Comment: Maybe it will help
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75606/how-to-set-and-configure-a-value-relation-edittype-in-qgis-2-0

Comment: could get there with OGR if that's an option (not sure about fiona or shapely).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I will sure have a look at OGR!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you have a QgsGeometry object (eg the geometry returned when calling QgsFeature.geometry()), you can access it's raw geometry info by calling QgsGeometry.geometry() in QGIS 2.x or QgsGeometry.constGet() in QGIS 3 respectively. This returns the relevant [QgsAbstractGeometry](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsAbstractGeometryV2.html) subclass for the geometry type. These subclasses have methods for reading points from the geometry as [QgsPointV2](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsPointV2.html) objects ([QgsPoint](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsPoint.html) in QGIS 3), which you can then directly retrieve the z or m values from. Sometimes (as is the case with [QgsLineStringV2](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLineStringV2.html) you can even directly access the z/m values from the subclass itself.

Here's an example for QGIS 2.x:

```
g = feature.geometry()
line = g.geometry() #line returns a QgsLineStringV2 object
m = line.mAt(0) # m value of first vertex
z = line.zAt(0) # z value of first vertex
```

And another example for QGIS 3:

```
g = feature.geometry()
line = g.constGet() #line returns a QgsLineString object
m = line.mAt(0) # m value of first vertex
z = line.zAt(0) # z value of first vertex
```

An important thing to note is that only very recent gdal versions support m values, and older versions read in m values as z values. This will affect your results if using a file based format (eg shapefiles) in QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

if you do look into OGR - a great resource is the [cookbook](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html#create-a-linestring). One example of writing z (m) values into a shapefile might be something like:

```
def mkline():
    drv=ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
    ds=drv.CreateDataSource('test.shp')
    lyr=ds.CreateLayer('test',ogr.wkbLineString25D)
    flddef=ogr.FieldDefn('Name',ogr.OFTString)
    flddef.SetWidth(32)
    lyr.CreateField(flddef)

    feat=ogr.Feature(lyr.GetLayerDefn())
    feat.SetField('Name','someDescriptor')
    line=ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString25D)
    line.AddPoint(1116651.439379124, 637392.6969887456, 100.) # x, y , z
    line.AddPoint(1188804.0108498496, 652655.7409537067, 200.)
    line.AddPoint(1226730.3625203592, 634155.0816022386, 300.)
    line.AddPoint(1281307.30760719, 636467.6640211721, 400.)
    feat.SetGeometry(line)
    lyr.CreateFeature(feat)

feat=None
ds=None
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! I will try to code it into the z-coordinate.