# Autocompletion with control element types of the attribute form in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table

With this code you can open a window with a LineEdit, which offers an automatic completion (here index 0).

```
    my_vector_layer = iface.activeLayer()
    w = qgis.gui.QgsFieldValuesLineEdit()
    w.setLayer(my_vector_layer)
    w.setAttributeIndex(0)
    w.show()
```

I want to embed this in the object form that appears after adding an object. I'm struggling a little with the PyQGIS documentation.
So it's going in this direction:

```
iface.openFeatureForm(layer, feat, True)
```

1. How do I get the above code embedded in openFeatureForm?
2. Generally I want a link with the attributes of another layer. Without PyQGIS this is possible in the layer properties under attribute form and value relation. But how do I address this and the other control element types of the attribute form in PyQGIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a specific widget for a specific field to add to the attribute form when it appear. This solution is based on this [code](https://gisunchained.wordpress.com/2019/09/30/configure-editing-form-widgets-using-pyqgis/) by Alexandre Neto and the accepted answer of this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204175/how-to-set-and-configure-a-value-relation-edittype-in-qgis-2-14#206604), [How to set and configure a value relation edittype in QGIS 2.14?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204175/how-to-set-and-configure-a-value-relation-edittype-in-qgis-2-14#206604) by Matthias Kuhn.

Here is the code :

```
my_vector_layer = iface.activeLayer() #layer you want to add features to
field = "test" #field you want to relate to another layer
field_idx = my_vector_layer.fields().indexFromName(field) #field index

target_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layername)[0] #target layer you want to relate to field
key_field = "id" #id field of the target layer
target_field = "test_1" #field of the target layer you want to relate to field

config = {'AllowMulti': False, #don't allow multi value
            'AllowNull': True, #allow NULL value
            'OrderByValue': True, #order by value
            'FilterExpression': '',
            'Key': key_field, #id field of the target layer
            'Value': target_field, #field from the target layer you want to relate
            'Layer': target_layer.id(), #target layer
            'UseCompleter': True} #True if you want the LineEdit tool, False if you want a list of value from the field of the target layer
            

widget_setup = QgsEditorWidgetSetup('ValueRelation',config) #setup a specific widget with Value Relation and the config dict create
my_vector_layer.setEditorWidgetSetup(field_idx, widget_setup) #add the widget to your layer and the field on your layer
```

This is the result with `UseCompleter` set to `True`
[image]

This is the result with `UseCompleter` set to `False`
[image]